# How to get a stackplot with PyQtGraph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqtgraph

The `stackplot` function from Matplotlib library can be used as follows :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr

x = np.linspace(0,10,50)
y = [npr.rand(50) for i in range(4)]

plt.stackplot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I need to use PyQtGraph library for a project :

```
    import pyqtgraph as pg
    from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
    import numpy as np
    import numpy.random as npr

    x = np.linspace(0,10,50)
    y = [npr.rand(50) for i in range(4)]

    win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
    graph = win.addPlot()
    #stackplot function
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

How can I get a stackplot?

Comment: If you want to get a solution for an X or Y library then you must create 2 questions: 1 for each library. In this case I have removed everything related to Vispy that you must place in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyqtgraph does not have a built-in stack plot feature, but you could write this yourself just by summing up the plot data before each line to be stacked, and using `PlotCurveItem`'s `fillLevel` and `fillBrush` arguments. Example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(size=(7,10), scale=0.1, loc=1)
stacked = np.cumsum(data, axis=0)

plt = pg.plot()
for i,row in enumerate(stacked):
    curve = plt.plot(row, fillLevel=0, fillBrush=(i,10))
    curve.setZValue(10-i)
```

Comment: I did not mention in my question that I would like to display a real-time plot. Before your answer, I created a curve y = 0, used fills = [pg.FillBetweenItem(y, curve_1), ..., pg.FillBetweenItem(curve_n_minus_1, curve_n)] and graph.addItem(f) for f in fills. I updated the graph using graph.clear(), setData on each curve, recreating the fills variable and adding f to the graph at each iteration. Your solution, combined with `setData` is ~8x faster, thank you very much !